# Change ip address used by application (application layer)

Tags: c#, wmi, web-controls

We have a windows server with 20 ip's bound to the nic. At the moment we are successfully performing (web)requests by (automaticaly) changing the IP's once in a while (`request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(connectionInfo.BindIPEndPointCallback);`). Since a couple of days we have decided to use a test environment where we use the WebBrowser control of .NET to make the web request.
Here the problem starts, because we cant't give an endpoint like solution to change the ip the webcontrol is using. This is why we've decided to change the IP programmaticaly but whenever we change the IP via WMI, we are getting identified with a single ip adress (all the time).

This is the wmi code:

```
public static void setIP(string IpAddresses, string SubnetMask, string Gateway)
    {
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if ((bool)mo["IPEnabled"]==true)
            {
                ManagementBaseObject newIP = mo.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                ManagementBaseObject newGate = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
                ManagementBaseObject newDNS = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");

                newGate["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { Gateway };
                newGate["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };

                newIP["IPAddress"] = IpAddresses.Split(',');
                newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { SubnetMask };

                ManagementBaseObject setIP = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                ManagementBaseObject setGateways = mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGate, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

The server runs on VM Ware but I dont think this can be the problem.
What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, but you pass multiple ip addresses to EnableStatic, but only a single subnet mask, which might cause the problem.
Try to pass a subnet mask for every ip address, i.e. change the assignment of newIP["SubnetMask"] to:

```
 newIP["SubnetMask"] = Enumerable.Repeat(SubnetMask, newIP["IPAddress"].Length).ToArray();
```

And make sure you do not have any spaces in the IpAddresses argument

Comment: I think my question was not clear. I already have all ip's bound to the NIC, I only want to decide myself which ip to use for this application.